# GCM Notifications stopped working with PushSharp

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am suddenly receiving this error below when an existing app is trying to send `notifications`.  It has not been upgraded to Firebase yet and is in process.  Did Google shut down the ability to send `GCM notifications`?

> {"ClassName":"PushSharp.Android.GcmMessageTransportException","Message":"Internal
>   Service
>   Error","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"
>   at
>   PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.processResponseError(GcmAsyncParameters
>   asyncParam)\r\n   at
>   PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.responseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nprocessResponseError\nPushSharp.Android,
>   Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cf74b75eab2c0170\nPushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel\nVoid
>   processResponseError(GcmAsyncParameters)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"PushSharp.Android","WatsonBuckets":null}

The OnNotificationFailed returns the following in the Exception:

```
PushSharp.Android.GcmMessageTransportException: Internal Service Error
   at PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.processResponseError(GcmAsyncParameters asyncParam)
   at PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.responseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you could retry sending your request if you encounter Internal Service Error as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes). You may want to check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) for more information and sample usages. And if you plan to upgrade to Firebase, this [thread](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/752) might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to just ignore this and get our release done for Firebase.  This seems to be an intermittent issue.  We are just going to use the rest services for firebase instead of PushSharp.